# phpMyAdmin: mysqli_query mysql, не получается применить where

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Памагите, жопа горит нимагу уже.
Делаю запрос через php в SQl:

$connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "mysql", "mysql", "test_bd");
$count_class = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `persons` WHERE `class` = `Ассасин` ");
$count_class_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_class);

Выдает:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\test\index.php on line 128

Причем такой запрос прекрасно работает (ищет класс поле которого занимает единица):
$count_class = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `persons` WHERE `class` = 1 ");

И такой запрос работает тоже (выбираем где id=1):
$count_class = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `persons` WHERE `id` = 1 ");

То есть все работает и проблема возникает именно тогда когда я пытаюсь выбрать столбцы по строке Ассасин либо любому другому слову. Думал что проблема в кириллице, но я ввел имя класса на латинице и пробовал найти его, но тоже не получилось, ровно такая же ошибка. Коннекта по такому запросу не происходит

Comment: А суть в том что кавычки и бэктики имеют разное значение в тексте запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Я прожил 26 лет и даже не подозревал что верхние одинарные кавычки оказывается бывают разные, и то что php оказывается не все равно какие ему скармливают.
Вот это ` не равно ', и об этом нигде и никакой информации сказано не было, ни в одном мануале и уроке.